# How to make stored procedure with bulk insert from Blob storage?

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, blob

Im building a stored procedure to bulk insert from a .csv file located on Azure Blob Storage. I got it to work, by passing storage name + filename, and the SAS code. At first, it was ok, I ran the sp with a true value and got it to work.

The problem is, my sp has 3 parameters, path, file and sas, but they`re not "regular values" on a SQL query, they are like table and credential references.

Examples:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ProcessarPlanilha
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = @sas


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
CREDENTIAL = ProcessarPlanilha,
          LOCATION = @path)

BULK INSERT tb_pessoa_sga_data_etl
FROM @file
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
      FORMAT = 'CSV',
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
      CODEPAGE = 65001,
      DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar')
```

Using this throws an error of `incorret syntax near @sas`.

How should I proceed? I tried to create a table type, to set as the value in @file, but didnt work as well.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for the parts that require literals. Though I wouldn't expect that you would need to create these credentials *every* time you run the procedure; you just need to create them the once and that would be *outside* of the procedure.

Comment: Actually, the SAS is generated for every file, so I would need to generate them every time, no?

Comment: The moment you try to create the credential a second time, you'll get an error that one with the name `ProcessarPlanilha` already exists; unless you are dropping them after you use them,,? Of course, that'll mean that if 2 connections try to execute the procedure at the same time, you would get errors too.

Comment: Before creating, I`m checking if it already exists, and if so, drops it.

Comment: But still, many thanks for ur help Larnu, I`ll study a bit more on dynamic sql and how to change my query to adapt to it.